# Applying Single Responsibility principle on class?

Tags: java, solid-principles, design-principles

**Single Responsibility Principle(SRP) :-**

Every class should have single responsibility. Basically, there should be a single reason to change. I am not sure
what exactly the last statement means.  My interpretation is that to design the classes in a way that there should be a single reason to change is there can be a single method because each method is a behavior and hence reason. Is that correct?  If not what exactly defines the reason?

Consider a stock exchange system where most of dev comes up with design where StockService.java has both buy and sell methods. Here there will be two reasons(buy and sell) to change this class

```
public class StockService {
    
   private String name = "ABC";
   private int quantity = 10;

   public void buy(){
      System.out.println("Stock [ Name: "+name+", 
         Quantity: " + quantity +" ] bought");
   }
   public void sell(){
      System.out.println("Stock [ Name: "+name+", 
         Quantity: " + quantity +" ] sold");
   }
   
   // other methods related to socks
}
```

To follow SRM principle, do I need to come up separate class where StockBuyService.java(containing buy related methods) and StockSellService(containing sell related methods). is it ?

Comment: The number of methods isn't the relevant factor. See [is the single responsibility principle applicable to functions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/275646/is-the-single-responsibility-principle-applicable-to-functions) on the software engineering SE. It's related to the actors or roles in the use cases and not the number of methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  The `buy()` and `sell()` methods make sense together when you consider the purpose of the class is `StockService`.  From the name, it is reasonable to expect that a stock service will handle trade requests from an investor, and those trade requests can be either `buy()` or `sell()`.  (As a matter of fact, a stock service with a single method `trade()` may risk violating the Interface Segregation Principle, depending on how it's implemented.)

There may be a case for splitting apart buying and selling internal to this class, and that would be if you have to handle all types of trades together, yet implement different rules or regulations for each type.  In that case, you might consider using the strategy pattern, which uses polymorphism to implement the rules based on the type of trade that is occurring.  But your sample class doesn't get into those kinds of details, so following the [YAGNI principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), you're not there yet.

But since you are asking the question, that's an indicator that the name may not be clear enough.  (In the practice of refactoring, this is known as a *code smell*.)  This is a good time to review it and ask yourself if the class is properly named.  Is this truly a stock service?  Would you have been as uncertain if the class had been named `StockTradingService`?  Can you think of a better name that more clearly expresses the purpose this class serves?  I'm not saying it's a bad name, or that it must be changed; I'm only saying that you should recognize that having to ask the question should raise a little 'caution' flag in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

First, as @MatsLindh commented, the number of methods isn't a factor when evaluating SRP.

Let's investigate the StockService! If you want your StockService to have one responsibility you should find that one responsibility which usually means you have to define a simple goal at a proper layer of abstraction for your service.

For example, the goal of StockService can be to manage a trade, or in other words, describe the flow of a trade. In that case, StockService will be something like this:

```
public class StockService{
  PriceService priceService;
  AccountService accountService;
  Stock stock

  public void buy(int amount){
    int fullPrice = getFullPrice(amount);
    if(accountService.hasEnoughMoney(fullPrice){
         accountService.buyStock(stock, amount, fullPrice)
    }
  }
  public void sell(int amount){
     accountService.sellStock(stock,amount)
  }
  private int getFullPrice(int amount){
     return amount * priceService.getPrice(stock);
  }
}
```

As you can see the class has only one responsibility: manage a trade. It doesn't know anything about the details (how do you implement check or buy).
The only reason to change the class is a change in the trading flow.

In my opinion, SRP is all about finding the proper level of abstraction to define a goal and implement as little code or logic as possible to cover that goal and let the other classes do the rest.